# Is a has_many through relationship possible with 4 models in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationships

For example a list and a sublist can have many items through a model called list_items.

Here are the models

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sublists
    has_many :list_items
    has_many :items, through: :list_items
end

class Sublist < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    has_many :list_items
    has_many :items, through: :list_items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :list_items
    has_many :lists,through: :list_items
    has_many :sublists, through: :list_items
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :sublist
  belongs_to :item
end
```

This below is what i am trying to accomplish.

**Items Library Page**

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
```

**Lists Page**

```
=============================
=List 1                     =
=============================
=Item 2                     =
=Item 4                     =
=Sublist Start              =
=Item 5                     =
=Item 1                     =
=Item 3                     =
=============================
```

So an item without a sublist (like item 2 and item 4) would have the following fields populated in the List_Item Model

```
List_id = 1

Sublist_id = nil

Item_id = 1
```

An item with a sublist (like item 5 and item 1 and item 3) would have the following fields populated in the List_Item Model

```
List_id = 1

Sublist_id = 1

Item_id = 1
```

The reason i would like to do it this way is so i can do drag and drop by dragging to the sublist it will populate the sublist_id and by dragging out of the sublist the sublist_id will then be nil.

Would this be possible or is there a better way to do this this?

Comment: Your `associations` in `Item` model are wrong FYI.

Comment: All the associations seems to be fine.

Comment: I just changed it there was an extra has_many :lists, through: :list_items in my Items Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes, that's possible:

```
class A
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs
  has_many :ds, through: :cs
end

class B
  has_many :cs
  belongs_to :a
end

class C
  has_many :ds
  belongs_to :b
end

class D
  belongs_to :c
end
```

If th association on A is named differently than the association on B, you need to supply the `source` parameter to the `through`-relation, like this:

```
class A
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs, source: :ccs
end

class B
  has_many :cs, as: :ccs
  belongs_to :a
end

class C
  belongs_to :b
end
```

This will allow you to:

```
A.find(1).bs # => collection of B-instances
A.find(1).cs # => collection of C-instances
```

I'm not sure, if this answers your question. I hope so, but I'm a little confused about your example, so if not, please do comment :)

Comment: you're one class short: how would all of this work if there was a fourth model - i.e. if there was a class D?

Comment: You can continue this chain as much as you'd like. Simply add appropriate belongs_to to subsequent, new classes and has_many all the way up the chain of classes.

Comment: shall I write to amend your answer, what if I want to connect class D and class A?

Comment: You continue the chain you need to add `has_many :ds` to class A, and then chain this all the way through the inheritance tree.

Comment: thank you - but what exactly do you mean by "chaining this all the way through the inheritance tree"? Is it possible to ammend the above to show how this would be like - that would be most helpful to 1000s of future readers

Comment: Ok. I added the additional class to the example. You should really read up on ActiveRecord's relationships to get a better understanding of the solution.

Comment: thank you i understand perfectly now! very helpful answer. the activeRecords guide on rails didn't have a clear solution (when i had a quick glance through it) so had to go to SO.