# Linking many existing models to one new one. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, relationships

So I am making an app that reviews books, articles and the like.

I have created the backbone of the app by creating models, views, controllers etc for Piece(the book or article), Section(self explanatory), Subsection, and Subsubsection.

I want to add a new model into the mix, a "Links" model (which will just be a link to another source or website). My issue is that I don't know how to make ALL of my previously stated models have "Links". I want each of The above models to have access and CRUD capabilities to their "Links", but so far all i have read about is has_many or has_and_belongs_to_many.

As far as I understand, those kinds of relations only relate ONE model to ONE other model, even if Piece might have many Sections, it only relates these two models.

I guess the Links model would have to have an obligatory piece_id, but then optional id's such as: section_id, subsection_id depending on where the link was. So if in Chapter 3 of my first book i want to add a link, it would have an obligatory piece_id=1 and then a section_id=3, but then no subsection_id or subsubsection_id.

So how do I go about creating a model such that it belongs to several other models? Or is this even possible?

https://github.com/kingdavidek/StuddyBuddy

Comment: So it can belong to one of the other models?  Or belong to many of them at once?

Comment: The idea is that it would belong to one, but that depending on which one, it could belong to many. There is a nested relationship between **Piece >> Section >> Subsection >> Subsubsection** so if i wanted to create a new **Link** in a **Subsection**, it would belong to **Subsection**, but also to **Section** and **Piece** because of the nested relationship.

Comment: You can use has_many through relationship.Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358679/is-a-has-many-through-relationship-possible-with-4-models-in-rails

Comment: @Kingdavidek could you give some real-world examples for piece, section, subsection, subsubsection and links? I don't really understand how they fit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty good use case for [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) associations. For simplicity lets start out with a one to many relationship:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links, as: :linkable
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links, as: :linkable
end
```

Here the `links` table will have `linkable_id` (int) and `linkable_type` (string) columns. One important thing to take note of here is that `linkable_id` is not a true foreign key from the RBDMS point of view. Rather ActiveRecord resolves which table the relation points to when it loads the relation.

If we want to cut the duplication we can create a module which contains the desired behavior. Using [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) cuts a lot of the boilerplate code involved in creating such a module.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end

# app/models/concerns/linkable.rb
module Linkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :links, as: :linkable
  end
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Linkable
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Linkable
end
```

So how would we make a polymorpic many to many relation?

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :linkings
end

# this is the join model which contains the associations between
# Links and the "linkable" models 
class Linking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :link
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end

# app/models/concerns/linkable.rb
module Linkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :links, through: :linkings, as: :linkable
  end
end

class Piece < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Linkable
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Linkable
end
```

On a side note - a better way to build a hierarchy between sections would be to use a single Section model and [give it a self joining relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Section'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Section', 
                      foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer this seems like exactly what I need, although I don't get it all completely just yet I'll look up the jargon etc. to try and understand it. For the self joining relationship thing, are you referring to the nested models Piece>> Section>> Subsection etc. Would your way make it such that you could essentially go section>>section>> section>> ad infinitum?

Comment: "Would your way make it such that you could essentially go section>>section>> section>> ad infinitum?" - yes exactly. I would really recommend reading through the rails [guides article on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) top to bottom as the is pretty advanced stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it sounds like essentially you want a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
class Link
  belongs_to :linkable, polymorphic: true
end

class Piece
  has_many :links, as: :linkable
end
```

Link would need `linkable_id` integer column and `linkable_type` string column.  You can then use it in the same way as an ordinary `has_many` to `belongs_to` association

> if i wanted to create a new Link in a Subsection, it would belong to
>   Subsection, but also to Section and Piece because of the nested
>   relationship

This bit rails can't help with, you'd need to write your own method to find all the links in the chain of items.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I suppose it would be too hard for the nested relationship thing to have it linked to a subsection for example, and then just find the parent id's all the way up the tree?

Comment: @Kingdavidek if you look at the ruby gems for tree structures like closure tree or ancestry many of them have this functionality input