# Can't access field through 3 models in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm trying to do something very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358679/is-a-has-many-through-relationship-possible-with-4-models-in-rails)

I have 4 models, one of which (CoffeeBlend) is a join table:

```
class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_beans, through: :coffee_blends
    has_one :country, through: :coffee_beans
end

class CoffeeBean < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_roasts, through: :coffee_blends
    belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :coffee_beans
end

class CoffeeBlend < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coffee_bean
    belongs_to :coffee_roast
end
```

My `coffee_beans` table has a column called `country_id` which is populated with the id from the `countries` table.

In my `coffee_roasts_show` I want to be able to pull the associated country of the coffee bean. My latest attempt looks like

```
<% @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.country.country_name %>
```

which gives `undefined method 'country'`

Or

```
<% @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.countries.country_name %>
```

returns `undefined method 'countries'`

Do I have my associations correct?  Is my show code wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `@coffee_roast.coffee_beans` returns you association, not a single record. That's why you cannot call `#country` on that. If you need all the countries, you can use `#map`:

```
<% @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.map {|cb| cb.country.country_name } %>
```

Edit:

If you want to show the list in the browser, add `=` to your ERB mark:

```
<%= @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.map {|cb| cb.country.country_name } %>
```

It may also be useful to explicitly convert contry names to a string with [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
<%= @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.map {|cb| cb.country.country_name }.join(', ') %>
```

Comment: I only need one country.

Comment: You have multiple coffee beans, which one shodl provide you the country?

Comment: in `coffee_blends` join table I have coffee_bean_id with the bean id.

Comment: Still you have multiple `coffee_blends` per `coffee_roast`. Which country you want to show?

Comment: Just looking in the terminal, I can see after using your code above, It's now pulling through the country_id, but I don't have anything written in the browser.

Comment: I see it was missing an `=`. I now have what looks like an array in the browser `["El Salvador", "Guatemala"]`

Comment: I need to play around with how I display the country inline with bean in the show page, but I am now at least bringing the country name through, so will mark as solved.

Comment: pls consider upvoting, to me it's worth (even) more than accepting