# Trying to display records from chained models on Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53888615/cant-access-field-through-3-models-in-rails-5/53888652)

```
class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_beans, through: :coffee_blends
    has_one :country, through: :coffee_beans
end

class CoffeeBean < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_roasts, through: :coffee_blends
    belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :coffee_beans
end

class CoffeeBlend < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coffee_bean
    belongs_to :coffee_roast
end
```

I am able to show the related `coffee_beans` on the `coffee_roasts` show page, and also the `country`, however, I can not work out how to display them correctly.

My current code is attempting to show the bean and its related country on the same row on the table, however the top is blank and the two countries are both in the second row.

**coffee_roasts/show.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="display-3"><%= @coffee_roast.name %></h1>
      <p>
        by <h2 class="display-6"><%= @coffee_roast.roaster.roaster_name %></h2>
      </p>

<div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="table">
 <thead>     
    <tr>
      <th>Bean</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
 <% @coffee_roast.coffee_blends.each do |blend| %>
    <tr>
  <th><%= blend.coffee_bean.name %>

    <% end %></th>
  <th><%= @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.map {|cb| cb.country.country_name }.join(', ') %></th>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

### Bean            | Country

### El Martillo             |

Finca La Cumbre     |  El Salvador, Guatemala

`El Salvador` show be in-line with the `El Martillo` bean.

My approach feels quite wrong here, but I'm pretty new to working with multiple levels of models so still learning.

How can I get the beans associated country to display alongside the bean?

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a lot simpler than I thought. I've found the below works perfectly. No need to map an array.

```
<tbody>
  <% @coffee_roast.coffee_blends.each do |blend| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= blend.coffee_bean.name %></td>
    <td><%= blend.coffee_bean.country.country_name %></td> #this bit was the original concern.
    <td><%= blend.coffee_bean.variety %></td>
    <td><%= blend.coffee_bean.process %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>   
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
  <% @coffee_roast.coffee_blends.each do |blend| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= blend.coffee_bean.name %></td>
      <td><%= @coffee_roast.coffee_beans.map {|cb| cb.country.country_name }.join(', ') %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>  
</tbody>
```

try and see if this works?